# Any way to use self signed certificates on the windows phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate, emulation, ssl-certificate, self-signed

We are developing a WP7 application which is connected to a server using OAuth. **It's a low budget project.** So, we are only using **self signed certificates** even on the production server. That worked fine for the android client.

- Is there a chance to work with
  unsigned certificates on WP7 also?
- Is there a way to make the app work
  out of the box with this kind of
  certs? So, that the user doesn't
  need to install the cert manually?
- We failed to install the cert on the emulator. Did you have the same kind of problem? How did you solve it?
- Does Microsoft allow apps with this kind of certs in their market

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Set up an Authenticated Web Service for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN describes how to go about using authenticated services. According to [SSL Root Certificates for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), the only trusted certificate authorities are:

- AOL (USA)
- Comodo (USA)
- DigiCert (USA)
- Entrust (Canada)
- GlobalSign (UK)
- GoDaddy (USA)
- Keynectis (France)
- QuoVadis (Bermuda)

So I'd say that a self-signed certificate won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the emulator's browser to navigate to the .CER file that represents your self-signed root? That works on the physical hardware, and seems like it might work on the emulator as well. But you absolutely shouldn't expect to ship like this; a Go-Daddy cert is like $15/year.